# Filter dictionary where values is a class based on a class value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I made a dictionary where the key is an int, and the value is a class object.
sample of the code

```
public class Sample
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}
```

So my dictionary is structured as: `Dictionary<int, Sample>`

What I am trying to to is filter the dictionary based on one of the class values. so for example, i want to filter the dictionary based on where the Sample.name contains "left" for example.

I already tried several things, but i just cant seem to find just the right way to do so.
one if the last attempts i did, but didn't seem to work either:

```
 var match = Fulllist
        .Select(kv => new
        {
            id = kv.Key,
            item = kv.Value.name.Where(p => kv.Value.name.Equals("left",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        })
        .ToDictionary(k => k.id, v => v.item);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to filter a dictionary of Sample objects based on a specific condition for the name property of each Sample object. The code snippet you provided is close, but there are a couple of issues. You're using Where on a string, which is not correct, and you're also not checking if the name contains the substring "left". Additionally, you're creating a new dictionary with the filtered values, but you want to keep the original key-value pairs.

Here's the corrected code to achieve what you're looking for:

```
var filteredDictionary = Fulllist
.Where(kv => kv.Value.name.Contains("left", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply filter on the dictionary like that

```
var match = Fulllist.Where(x => x.Value.name.Contains("left",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

You can add any kind of filter after the x.Value